# How to Add Additional Column and Value to a MySQL Query INSERT SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have 2 columns **tbl_feestudent** and **tbl_feeschool** and this is their columns

feestudent_id, student_id, schoolyear_id, gradelevel_id, feetype_id, and feestudent_amount.

feeschool_id, schoolyear_id, gradelevel_id, feetype_id, and feeschool_amount.

I'm using a MySQL Query of INSERT SELECT where all the items that selected in **tbl_feeschool** will be inserted in **tbl_feestudent**

**tbl_feestudent** however has additional column which is **student_id**

How would I insert a value of **student_id** to all inserted values coming from **tbl_feeschool**

Let's just say the value of **student_id** is **40**, the table would like like this.

[image]

As of now this is my query of INSERT SELECT with WHERE schoolyear_id = 4 and gradelevel_id = 1.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_feestudent (schoolyear_id, gradelevel_id, feetype_id, feestudent_amount) 
SELECT schoolyear_id, gradelevel_id, feetype_id, feeschool_amount 
FROM tbl_feeschool 
WHERE schoolyear_id = 4 AND gradelevel_id = 1
```

Comment: Do you want to insert 40 as student id with above insert query??

Comment: Yeah, it's just an example. You may use 40 as value, I'll just change it in my code with a variable.

Comment: @Cecatrix check my answer. Is it working or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add id to your select query
suppose your student_id is `40` then

```
INSERT INTO tbl_feestudent (student_id,schoolyear_id, gradelevel_id, feetype_id, feestudent_amount) 
SELECT 40,schoolyear_id, gradelevel_id, feetype_id, feeschool_amount 
FROM tbl_feeschool 
WHERE schoolyear_id = 4 AND gradelevel_id = 1
```

Comment: Oh that work, I thought selecting 40 as value will have an error because it's not coming from tbl_feeschool.